# Str.Split for unknown number of values with insert statement for each?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If I dont know the number of comma separated values how can I store each value and then execute an insert statement for each value. So if the value of str is 123456,321654,321545 (I dont know that there will be 3 values ahead of time) how can I split all of em and do 3 inserts? I am thinking it would be a for each statement? But I am not sure how to do that with the .split? Can someone offer me some direction on this? My code below will just return the first value. Thank you

```
Dim str As String = Session("List")
    str = str.Split(",")(1)

    Return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that it will be a `foreach`. The `Split` method returns a `string[]`

```
For Each s As String In str.Split(","c)
    ' build the insert statement and execute
Next
```

Comment: This won't compile with Option Strict On.  EDIT:  Nevermind, you fixed it :)

Comment: @DouglasBarbin: Since the code was fixed it's difficult to see, but do you mean Option Infer Off? "On" is the default setting for vb though.

Comment: No, I meant Option Strict On.  He had originally left out the `c`, so it was a string being passed to the `.Split()` method

Comment: SO won't let me edit something so small, but the parentheses are imbalanced.

Answer (score 4):

You need to split the string.  Try this:

```
Dim str As String = DirectCast(Session("List"), String)
For Each item As String In str.Split(","c)
  ' Do stuff with item here
Next item
```

Comment: Thank you may I ask what the "C" does?

Comment: @user1342164 The `c` just after the double-quote specifies a Char as opposed to a String.